# Excel VBA out of memory error message then all excel files crash sometimes when I'm debugging, why?

Tags: excel, vba, memory

I created a macro on Excel VBA to automatize some standard tasks. Oftentimes I get an error message ("Out of memory") then when I click on either "ok" or if I close the message, it crashes and all excel files close without saving them. It's quite frustrating and I can't seem to identify the issue? Does anyone know the answer to this? I've inserted an example of my code below (btw I'm open to tips to make my coding more efficient, am learning...).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim FilePath$, Row$, Column$, Address$, SheetName$, i As Integer, numRows As Long, j As Long, wb, rowz As Variant, dummz As Variant, myVars As New Collection, curr As Variant, test As Variant
Unload Me

'Empty arrays
rowz = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
FindRow = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
dummy = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Dummy2 = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

'Workbook names
wb = Array("RJMC6", "RJPME8", "RJ Europe Flex 1", "RJSMC", "Heritage", "RJ Green impact") 'wb
Main = Array("RJMC", "RJPME", "RJEF", "RJSMC", "Heritage", "RJE+") 'onglets
'***********************************************************************************************************************************


'Error if file not found
If Dir(FilePath & Filename) = Empty Then
    MsgBox "The file " & Filename & " was not found; The file name might have been modified", , "File does not exist"
End If

'Erreur if movement already passed today
For i = 0 To 5
    If Controls("CheckBox" & i + 1) = True Then 'Si fonds a été selectionné
        rowz(i) = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("A1:A6000"))
        dummy(i) = rowz(i)
        If Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(i), 1) = Date Then
            MsgBox "Ordre a déjà été passé"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        rowz(i) = 0
    End If
Next i
'************************************************************************************************************************************

'********************************** PART 1 Movements************************************************************************
numRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Ordres").Range("A1:A500"))
For i = 3 To numRows + 1
'******** Rj Micro Caps
    If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 1) = "MicroCaps" And CheckBox1 Then 'Si ordre = Micro et si MC a été selectionné Then
        Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 1) = DateValue(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 3)) 'Date de nego
        Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 5) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 7) 'ISIN
        Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 8) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 10) 'Cours
        Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 9) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 11)  'Devise
        Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 13) = StrConv(Replace(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 2), "Broker_", ""), vbProperCase) 'Broker
        FindRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 4), Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Range("A:A"), 0)
        If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 5) = "BUY" Then
            Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 3) = "achat"
            Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 7) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
            Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Cells(FindRow, 19) - (Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 11))
        Else
             Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 3) = "vente"
             Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 7) = -Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
             Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Cells(FindRow, 19) + (Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 7) * Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Cells(FindRow, 7))
        End If
        Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Cells(FindRow, 5) = Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Cells(FindRow, 5) + Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 7) 'Ajuste la Quantité ds ptf
        Sample = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("TOTAL ACTIF", Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Range("A:A"), 0)
        Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(0) + 1, 32) = Workbooks("RJMC6").Sheets("RJMC").Cells(Sample, 5)
        rowz(0) = rowz(0) + 1
        End If
  '**** RJ Small Caps
    If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 1) = "rj_smallcaps" And CheckBox2 Then
        Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 1) = DateValue(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 3)) 'Date de nego
        Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 5) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 7) 'ISIN
        Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 8) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 10) 'Cours
        Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 9) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 11) 'Devise
        Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 13) = StrConv(Replace(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 2), "Broker_", ""), vbProperCase) 'Broker
        FindRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 4), Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Range("A:A"), 0)
        If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 5) = "BUY" Then
            Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 3) = "achat"
            Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 7) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
            Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Cells(FindRow, 19) - (Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 11))
        Else
             Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 3) = "vente"
             Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 7) = -Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
             Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Cells(FindRow, 19) + (Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 7) * Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Cells(FindRow, 7))
        End If
        Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Cells(FindRow, 5) = Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Cells(FindRow, 5) + Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 7) 'Ajuste la Quantité ds ptf
        Sample = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("TOTAL ACTIF", Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Range("A:A"), 0)
        Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(1) + 1, 32) = Workbooks("RJPME8").Sheets("RJPME").Cells(Sample, 5) 'ActifNet
        rowz(1) = rowz(1) + 1
        End If
    '*******RJ Europe Flex
    If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 1) = "rj_europe_flex" And CheckBox3 Then
        Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 1) = DateValue(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 3)) 'Date de nego
        Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 5) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 7) 'ISIN
        Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 8) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 10) 'Cours
        Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 9) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 11) 'Devise
        Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 13) = StrConv(Replace(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 2), "Broker_", ""), vbProperCase) 'Broker
        FindRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 4), Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Range("A:A"), 0)
        If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 5) = "BUY" Then
            Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 3) = "achat"
            Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 7) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
            Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Cells(FindRow, 19) - (Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 11))
        Else
             Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 3) = "vente"
             Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 7) = -Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
             Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Cells(FindRow, 19) + (Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 7) * Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Cells(FindRow, 7))
        End If
        Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Cells(FindRow, 5) = Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Cells(FindRow, 5) + Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 7) 'Ajuste la Quantité ds ptf
        Sample = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("TOTAL ACTIF", Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Range("A:A"), 0)
        Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(2) + 1, 32) = Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("RJEF").Cells(Sample, 5)
        rowz(2) = rowz(2) + 1
        End If
    '******* RJ Smicro Caps
       If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 1) = "SMICROCAPS" And CheckBox4 Then
        Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 1) = DateValue(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 3)) 'Date de nego
        Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 5) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 7) 'ISIN
        Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 8) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 10) 'Cours
        Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 9) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 11) 'Devise
        Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 13) = StrConv(Replace(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 2), "Broker_", ""), vbProperCase) 'Broker
        FindRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 4), Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Range("A:A"), 0)
        If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 5) = "BUY" Then
            Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 3) = "achat"
            Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 7) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
            Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Cells(FindRow, 19) - (Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 11))
       Else
             Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 3) = "vente"
             Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 7) = -Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
             Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Cells(FindRow, 19) + (Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 7) * Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Cells(FindRow, 7))
        End If
        Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Cells(FindRow, 5) = Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Cells(FindRow, 5) + Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 7) 'Ajuste la Quantité ds ptf
        Sample = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("TOTAL ACTIF", Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Range("A:A"), 0)
        Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(3) + 1, 32) = Workbooks("RJSMC").Sheets("RJSMC").Cells(Sample, 5)
        rowz(3) = rowz(3) + 1
        End If
   '******** Rj Green Impact
    If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 1) = "rj_green_impact" And CheckBox6 Then
        Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 1) = DateValue(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 3)) 'Date de nego
        Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 5) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 7) 'ISIN
        Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 8) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 10) 'Cours
        Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 9) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 11) 'Devise
        Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 13) = StrConv(Replace(Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 2), "Broker_", ""), vbProperCase) 'Broker
        FindRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 4), Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Range("A:A"), 0)
        If Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 5) = "BUY" Then
            Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 3) = "achat"
            Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 7) = Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
            Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Cells(FindRow, 19) - (Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 11))
        Else
             Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 3) = "vente"
             Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 7) = -Sheets("Ordres").Cells(i, 9) 'Quantité
             Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Cells(FindRow, 19) = Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Cells(FindRow, 19) + (Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 7) * Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Cells(FindRow, 7))
        End If
        Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Cells(FindRow, 5) = Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Cells(FindRow, 5) + Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 7) 'Ajuste la Quantité ds ptf
        Sample = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("TOTAL ACTIF", Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Range("A:A"), 0)
        Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("Mouvements").Cells(rowz(5) + 1, 32) = Workbooks("RJ Green impact").Sheets("RJE+").Cells(Sample, 6)
        rowz(5) = rowz(5) + 1
        End If
    Next i
'************************************************************************************************************************************************

'*************************************************PART 2 - Cash********************************************************************
For i = 0 To 5
    If Controls("CheckBox" & i + 1) Then
        For Each curr In Array("EUR", "CHF", "GBP", "NOK", "DKK", "SEK", "USD", "PLN")
        Dummy2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("I" & dummy(i) & ":I" & rowz(i)), curr)
        If Dummy2 > 0 Then
            Achat = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Achat " & curr, Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets(Main(i)).Range("A:A"), 0)
            Vente = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Vente " & curr, Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets(Main(i)).Range("A:A"), 0)
            Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets(Main(i)).Cells(Achat, 3) = -Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("V100:V6000"), Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("I100:I6000"), curr, Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("A100:A6000"), Date, Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("C100:C6000"), "achat")
            Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets(Main(i)).Cells(Vente, 3) = -Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("V100:V6000"), Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("I100:I6000"), curr, Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("A100:A6000"), Date, Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("C100:C6000"), "vente")
            End If
        Next
        FDG = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Frais SG", Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets(Main(i)).Range("A:A"), 0)
        Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets(Main(i)).Cells(FDG, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("AB100:AB6000"), Workbooks(wb(i)).Sheets("Mouvements").Range("A100:A6000"), Date)  'Frais SG
    End If
Next i
MsgBox "Ordres validés, merci"
```

Comment: Out of memory means your Excel is using too much memory and therefore crashes. Use less or switch to the 64 bit edition of Excel. The 32 bit edition has a limit of 2 Gb of memory (no matter how much is installed).

Comment: A recommendation for your code (will not solve your issue but will make it readable). Declare variables for your sheets like `Dim WsMove As Worksheet` and  `Set WsMove = Workbooks("RJ Europe Flex 1").Sheets("Mouvements")` so your code gets shorter like `WsMove.Cells(…)` and learn how to use `With` blocks to make it even more readable.

Comment: Looks like you have many workbooks open. Depending on how big they are this might kill Excel regarding memory.

Comment: The first thing you do in the Sub is `Unload Me`, then later you reference  Controls (presumably controls on the User Form).  Maybe move the Unload to the end of the sub.  And quality things on the form, eg Me.Controls